# MEKA: Evaluation failed(CV): java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException:-1

Tags: multilabel-classification

MEKA is the open source machine learning framework. I have a created a *.arff file for text contents for solving the multi-label classification. But I couldn't execute the data. I am getting the following error when I run the Binary relevance based Naive Bayes method for my *.arff file.

```
Evaluation failed (CV):
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException:1
```

I have also compared the data format with the existing datasets like imdb.arff, bibtext.arff.
The data format looks as below:

```
@relation 'MovieR: -C 0'
@attribute Ease {0,1}
@attribute Satis {0,1}
@attribute Effect {0,1}
@attribute 000 numeric
@attribute 1 numeric
@attribute 10 numeric
@attribute 1000 numeric
...
...
...
@data
{0 1,2 1,4 1,8 1,18 1,31 1,42 1,45 1,48 1,58 1,74 1,76 1,82 1,95 1,96 1,100 1,135 1,142 1,151 1,157 1,161 1,165 1,175 1,178 1,192 1,197 1,198 1,200 1,207 1,210 1,213 1,222 1,224 1,240 1,244 1,252 1,263 1,269 1,296 1,313 1,321 1,326 1,328 1,373 1,387 1,390 1,391 1,393 1,395 1,417 1,432 1,437 1,439 1,455 1,466 1,467 1,473 1}
{1 1,4 1,14 1,29 1,30 1,32 1,52 1,78 1,98 1,111 1,135 1,138 1,141 1,143 1,153 1,157 1,164 1,185 1,187 1,195 1,206 1,213 1,234 1,289 1,297 1,323 1,326 1,328 1,332 1,395 1,403 1,432 1,444 1,445 1,446 1,478 1}
{0 1,2 1,42 1,45 1,54 1,58 1,185 1,212 1,239 1,401 1,417 1,432 1}
{0 1,1 1,2 1,6 1,14 1,18 1,29 1,42 1,45 1,48 1,58 1,82 1,86 1,87 1,95 1,96 1,109 1,119 1,131 1,135 1,142 1,149 1,158 1,177 1,187 1,208 1,216 1,223 1,227 1,245 1,249 1,250 1,263 1,274 1,279 1,281 1,296 1,299 1,306 1,315 1,316 1,317 1,328 1,345 1,376 1,395 1,397 1,421 1,428 1,432 1,437 1,439 1,446 1,456 1,466 1,470 1,473 1,474 1,476 1,482 1,483 1}
{2 1,4 1,32 1,35 1,41 1,44 1,49 1,56 1,87 1,116 1,165 1,187 1,196 1,258 1,277 1,297 1,328 1,366 1,378 1,399 1,420 1,435 1,436 1,446 1,456 1,485 1}
{0 1,1 1,14 1,29 1,35 1,38 1,40 1,41 1,44 1,49 1,56 1,58 1,59 1,69 1,72 1,75 1,88 1,91 1,93 1,99 1,109 1,120 1,129 1,142 1,147 1,157 1,167 1,188 1,192 1,200 1,216 1,223 1,233 1,263 1,264 1,265 1,268 1,272 1,300 1,310 1,321 1,328 1,330 1,331 1,338 1,340 1,347 1,354 1,356 1,361 1,364 1,370 1,376 1,380 1,387 1,397 1,399 1,401 1,417 1,421 1,432 1,437 1,439 1,446 1,464 1,466 1,482 1,483 1}
{9 1,18 1,22 1,25 1,29 1,42 1,45 1,54 1,66 1,70 1,72 1,86 1,92 1,95 1,134 1,140 1,149 1,153 1,187 1,199 1,207 1,215 1,235 1,239 1,275 1,279 1,285 1,289 1,290 1,296 1,301 1,317 1,326 1,328 1,336 1,344 1,369 1,374 1,386 1,424 1,430 1,432 1,451 1,465 1,468 1,469 1,481 1,482 1}
...
...
...
```

I would be thankful if you are able to help me on this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you must specify number of categories in this line @relation 'MovieR: -C 0'

for example: if it is the first 2 attributes then it will be: @relation 'MovieR: -C 2'

if it is the last 2 attributes, then it will be: @relation 'MovieR: -C -2'